# Is it fine to get '204 No Content' in PATCH method

Tags: api, patch

I am making a `PATCH` request to update a contact in Salesforce via API. The resource seems to be updated fine, but it returns me `204 No Content` in POSTMAN.

To my knowledge, it just means that there was no body returned in response which makes sense, since its `PATCH` method. But just wanted to confirm,  Is it an error that I should be worried about?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`204 No Content` does not mean an error code. It still reflects a successful operation. This is from the [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/204):

> The common use case is to return 204 as a result of a PUT request, updating a resource, without changing the current content of the page displayed to the user.

Additionally, [Status Codes and Error Responses](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/errorcodes.htm) documentation lists the different status codes that are used in Salesforce REST API Contexts.

Irrespective of the context where it is used, the status code `204` is always a successful response.

Comment: It's worth noting from a general web development point of view that *any* 2xx response code should be considered successful (3xx means redirection, 4xx means a problem with the client request, and 5xx means a problem with the server).

Answer (score 4):

HTTP status code 204 is returned if an existing record is updated.

here are the salesforce docs on `PATCH`

> JSON example response HTTP status code 204 is returned if an existing record is updated.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/dome_upsert.htm#!

Answer (score 2):

It is fine to get `204 No Content` using the `PATCH` method as long as you are using [`REST API`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/dome_upsert.htm) version `45.0` and earlier:

> In API version 45.0 and earlier, the HTTP status code is 204 (No Content) and there is no response body

> In API version 46.0 and later, the HTTP status code is 200 (OK) and the successful response is:

```js
{
    "id" : "001D000000Kv3g5IAB",
    "success" : true,
    "errors" : [ ],
    "created": false
}
```